# How does recursion works if call this twice?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have function:

```
function do(n) {
    if (n == 1) return;
    do(n-1);
    print "Recursion";
    do(n-1);
}
```

How does recursion work? Will be called the second `do()`?

Could you explain step by step, because I confues if I call `do()` it turns cursor to beginning of function `do()` to call it again, then as I think the second `do()` is not callable.

Comment: "*it turns cursor to veginnion of function*", no you *call* the function again, so it's a new instance, you don't rewind back to the beginning.

Comment: Your function's syntax is invalid, see snippet, you might consider fixing it

Comment: Fixed, check out again

Comment: Can you please explain what your understanding of recursion with a single call is?

Comment: I think this lie this, if  I call recursion function inside I move to the beginning of this function again. Therefore all code below is not called until recursion is not finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand recursion you must understand the concept of a call stack. Each function call, whether recursive or not, places a new call context on the stack with its own set of parameters and its own copy of local vairables. When the function returns, the context is popped from the stack and you return your "cursor" (which line you're on, variable states, etc) to where it was in the previous context. So if you have:

```
function doSomething(n) {
  if (n == 1) return;
  doSomething(n-1);
  console.log("Recursion");
  do(n-1);
}
```

(renamed because `do` is a keyword and `print` is *not* a keyword)

...and you have a call `doSomething(3)`, here's what you'll see step by step:

```
> = where we currently are

Call stack                Variables
------------------------  ---------
> doSomething             n: 3
```

```
doSomething               n: 3
> doSomething             n: 2
```

```
doSomething               n: 3
  doSomething             n: 2
>   doSomething           n: 1
```

```
doSomething               n: 3
  doSomething             n: 2
    doSomething           n: 1
>     return
```

```
doSomething               n: 3
  doSomething             n: 2
>   console.log("Recursion")
```

```
doSomething               n: 3
  doSomething             n: 2
>   doSomething           n: 1
```

```
doSomething               n: 3
  doSomething             n: 2
    doSomething           n: 1
>     return
```

```
doSomething               n: 3
  doSomething             n: 2
>   return
```

```
doSomething               n: 3
> console.log("Recursion")
```

...etc.

Comment: I did not get it, why `==` not `=`, I did not get really, is there illustration ?

Comment: I'm just trying to illustrate that each call stack item has its own version of the parameter with its own distinct value. Doesn't have anything to do with `=` or `==`. Updated to `:`, hopefully clearer.